# How to Perform Authentication for validating Google In App Subscription

Tags: python, google-api, in-app-purchase, google-oauth

I want to validate user subscription from `androidpublisher` API in server side. We have one month subscription for a product in our App. The cycle which we are following is below

- User will get product list. If he has subscribed, he will get full list of products. Otherwise he will get only free products.
- When user will subscribe, he will get a receipt from google for that purchase. That receipt will be saved in our database. Whenever user will demand list of products, that receipt will be validated from Google API. If it is valid, he will get full result. Otherwise partial.

Google has given below API for this purpose.

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/{packageName}/purchases/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/tokens/{token}

This Api requires authorization. I tried below code for this

```
receipt_json = json.loads(subscription_object.receipt)
service = build(serviceName='androidpublisher', version='v2', developerKey='key')
response = service.purchases().subscriptions().get(
        packageName=receipt_json.get('packageName'),
        subscriptionId=receipt_json.get('productId'),
        token=receipt_json.get('purchaseToken'))
```

But I got below response

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Please guide me how should I perform authorization before validating receipt. One importent point, I want to validate receipt in server side. Not client side. So user will not see or click any link in order to authorize this request.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like you are actually sending any authentication keys/tokens. You could try this to authenticate with OAuth2 credentials (access token or refresh token):

```
import httplib2
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2Credentials

credentials = OAuth2Credentials(...)
http = credentials.authorize(http=httplib2.Http())

service = build(serviceName='androidpublisher', version='v2', http=http)
```

Comment: I have `client_secret`, `client_id`. `OAuth2Credentials` atleast require `access_token`, `client_id`, `client_secret`, `refresh_token`, `token_expiry`, `token_uri` and `user_agent`. How can I get all other parameters.?

Comment: `access_token=None`, `token_expiry=datetime.datetime.now()`, `token_uri='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'`, `user_agent` you can set to whatever you want, usually it's your app name plus your app version, e.g. `'Hassans App 1.0'` (this will be used as the `User-Agent` header of the requests.)

Comment: Regarding `refresh_token` maybe [read this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). If you still have questions please give me more details about which of the scenarios in that link applies to your use case.

Comment: My scenario is like "Server to Server " application where I have to call Google API in order to check his subscription status when he gets list of products. So there will be no user involved.

Comment: For that you should use a service account, please read [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#serviceaccount) and [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount). Let me know if you have any specific problems. Second link is a detailed guide with code snippets.